# Loading / georeferencing OS rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, ordnance-survey

I have got some OS rasters but there isn't georeferencing file (TFW) with them. When I try to load them, it will obviously load in the wrong place. They are loading fine in a different GIS software (CadCorp) because the tile name is recognised (example:SJ86SW). Is that possible in QGIS? If not, while georeferencing the file can I snap to the corners of the raster to get the absolute position of these points?

Comment: http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/geo-referencing.html has the files (OS 50K)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the geo referencing files on our website for each of the raster products

[Download TFW Here](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/geo-referencing.html)

Download the correct zip file and unzip it into the same directory of your .tif files

Any GIS will then work with the raster files